# how to display xml content

Tags: asp.net, xml

i have an xml file with the following content

```
<root>
  <books>
     <foo>
       mathew
     </foo>
  </books>
</root>
```

i want to display the content mathew in a label How can i do that

Comment: We need to at least see the XML file content.

Comment: <Email>
  <NewUser>
    <Subject>alpha</Subject></NewUser></Email>

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the XML file is that basic as in your sample and the label is called `Label1`, you could manage with something like this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath);
while(reader.Read())
{
    if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "foo")
    {
        reader.Read();
        Label1.Text = reader.Value;
    }
}
```